# SVN Merge automated shell script

Tags: shell, unix, svn

I am working on shell script, which will automatically merge the different branches in SVN, but currently I stuck as am getting conflicts.

Can we resolve the conflicts by the script only?

Comment: What do you want to do in the case of conflicts?

Comment: if we want to add all the changes to the code like '.theirs', '.mine' or sometimes verify and add either of one.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can go download a GUI & use it to resolve conflicts. One of the more popular GUIs is: https://tortoisesvn.net/downloads.html It can also be used with a file comparison tool like http://winmerge.org

If you want to try to do this automatically, you may have to figure out which of these options that you'd like to use. These 2 come from Apache's  [Resolving Tree Conflicts](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/notes/tree-conflicts/resolution.txt) page:

```
svn resolve --accept=theirs
svn resolve --accept=mine
```

These 4 come from [RedBean.com's SVN 1.8 Basic Work Cycle page](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.tour.cycle.html#svn.tour.cycle.resolve):

```
svn resolve --accept=mine-conflict
svn resolve --accept=theirs-conflict
svn resolve --accept=mine-full
svn resolve --accept=theirs-full
svn resolve --accept=working
```

Comment: so we will require manual intervention for merging in SVN? or is there any other way we can automate the whole merging process.

Comment: The reason for the conflicts is to allow you to choose which version of the code should be used. If it's automated, it may end up breaking the code. Conflicted code injects extra characters like `<<<<<<` and `=======` and `>>>>>>>`, `.theirs`, `.mine`, etc... which are placeholders for where the code starts & stops at. Those extra characters will break your code. If you run a script to auto-merge them, then you'll probably have to go back in & manually delete those later on.

Comment: so can we keep both the changes using "svn resolve --accept"?

Comment: I've edited my answer to provide some examples of how to use the `svn resolve --accept` option. I've also included documentation links, which explain how they work. The examples are for choosing which version of the code, should trump the other one. To answer your question... No, but you can use `svn update` to keep both changes. The conflict markers will break the code, but you can look at both copies to see which one is preferred. Sometimes I'll use a GUI to help resolve conflicts. Othertimes, I'll manually edit them to delete those markers.